# I created a multiple choice c# console program and i placed a bonus stage but when it reaches it nothing shows up

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, console, console-application

I created a multiple choice c# console program and i placed a bonus stage which triggers if you score perfect 5 points but when it reaches it nothing shows up.
why?
all the other if's work except the bonus one can someone tell me how to resolve this?.
Sorry if my coding is very newbieish (int,string,if)

```
        {
        int score = 0;
        string ansr1 = "";
        string ansr2 = "";
        string ansr3 = "";
        string ansr4 = "";
        string ansr5 = "";
        string bonus1 = "";
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to my quiz user!(please type your'e answers in lower case letters)\nWhat is your'e name?\n");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Okay "+name+" lets start!\n");
        Console.Beep(500, 500);
        Console.Beep(500, 500);
        Console.Beep(500, 500);
        Console.Beep(660, 2500);
        Console.Clear();
        //no.1
        Console.WriteLine("Question 1\nWhat colour is the sky "+name+"?\na.blue\nb.green\nc.red\n");
        ansr1 = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();
        if (ansr1 == "a")
        {
            score = score + 1;
            Console.WriteLine("Correct!\n"+name+"'s score:"+score+"\n");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wrong!\n"+name+"'s score:"+score+"\n");
        }
        Console.Beep(600, 1500);
        Console.Clear();

        //no.2
        Console.WriteLine("Question 2\nHow many stars are there on the american flag "+name+"?\na.21\nb.72\nc.50\n");
        ansr2 = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();
        if (ansr2 == "c")
        {
            score = score+1;
            Console.WriteLine("Correct\n"+name+"'s score:"+ score+"\n");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wrong\n"+name+"'s score:"+score+"\n");
        }

        Console.Beep(700, 1500);
        Console.Clear();
        //no.3
        Console.WriteLine("Question 3\n"+name+",If you were in third place and you over take someone in second place what place would you be in now?\na.first\nb.second\nc.third\n");
        ansr3 = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();
        if (ansr3 == "b")
        {
            score = score+1;
            Console.WriteLine("Correct\n"+name+"'s score:" + score+"\n");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wrong\n"+name+"'s score:" + score+"\n");
        }

        Console.Beep(800, 1500);
        Console.Clear();
        //no.4
        Console.WriteLine("Question 4\n" + name + ",what is the tallest mountain in the world?\na.Everest\nb.Fuji\nc.Bromo\n");
        ansr4 = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();
        if (ansr4 == "a")
        {
            score = score + 1;
            Console.WriteLine("Correct\n" + name + "'s score:" + score + "\n");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wrong\n" + name + "'s score:" + score + "\n");
        }

        Console.Beep(900, 1500);
        Console.Clear();
        //no.5
        Console.WriteLine("Question 3\n" + name + ",If you were in third place and you over take someone in second place what place would you be in now?\na.first\nb.second\nc.third\n");
        ansr5 = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();
        if ((ansr5 == "b") && (score == 5))
        {
            //bonus level
            Console.WriteLine("Congratulations" + name + "you have scored a perfect 5!\nWould you like to enter the bonus stage?\nIf you lose this you lose the game\nbut if you pass you will receive 5 points.\nYes, or No?");
            bonus1 = Console.ReadLine();
            if (bonus1 == "yes")
            {

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
        else if (ansr5 == "b")
        {
            score = score + 1;
            Console.WriteLine("Correct\n" + name + "'s score:" + score + "\n");
        }


        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wrong\n" + name + "'s score:" + score + "\n");
        }

        Console.Beep(1000, 1500);
        Console.Clear();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: At the fifth question you are checking if `score == 5` while it can only be 4 at best.

Comment: It does nothing because it is empty :)

Comment: no the confirmation of the bonus level didnt appear,cos i was testing the bonus  confirmation.not the actual bonus question which i havent made yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best score can only be 4 while you are checking for score==5 for bonus. I think you forgot to increment score after fifth question. Either you have to check for score==4 or increment score after 5th question. Here is updated code.

```
 {
        int score = 0;
        string ansr1 = "";
        string ansr2 = "";
        string ansr3 = "";
        string ansr4 = "";
        string ansr5 = "";
        string bonus1 = "";
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to my quiz user!(please type your'e answers in lower case letters)\nWhat is your'e name?\n");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Okay "+name+" lets start!\n");
        Console.Beep(500, 500);
        Console.Beep(500, 500);
        Console.Beep(500, 500);
        Console.Beep(660, 2500);
        Console.Clear();
        //no.1
        Console.WriteLine("Question 1\nWhat colour is the sky "+name+"?\na.blue\nb.green\nc.red\n");
        ansr1 = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();
        if (ansr1 == "a")
        {
            score = score + 1;
            Console.WriteLine("Correct!\n"+name+"'s score:"+score+"\n");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wrong!\n"+name+"'s score:"+score+"\n");
        }
        Console.Beep(600, 1500);
        Console.Clear();

        //no.2
        Console.WriteLine("Question 2\nHow many stars are there on the american flag "+name+"?\na.21\nb.72\nc.50\n");
        ansr2 = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();
        if (ansr2 == "c")
        {
            score = score+1;
            Console.WriteLine("Correct\n"+name+"'s score:"+ score+"\n");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wrong\n"+name+"'s score:"+score+"\n");
        }

        Console.Beep(700, 1500);
        Console.Clear();
        //no.3
        Console.WriteLine("Question 3\n"+name+",If you were in third place and you over take someone in second place what place would you be in now?\na.first\nb.second\nc.third\n");
        ansr3 = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();
        if (ansr3 == "b")
        {
            score = score+1;
            Console.WriteLine("Correct\n"+name+"'s score:" + score+"\n");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wrong\n"+name+"'s score:" + score+"\n");
        }

        Console.Beep(800, 1500);
        Console.Clear();
        //no.4
        Console.WriteLine("Question 4\n" + name + ",what is the tallest mountain in the world?\na.Everest\nb.Fuji\nc.Bromo\n");
        ansr4 = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();
        if (ansr4 == "a")
        {
            score = score + 1;
            Console.WriteLine("Correct\n" + name + "'s score:" + score + "\n");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wrong\n" + name + "'s score:" + score + "\n");
        }

        Console.Beep(900, 1500);
        Console.Clear();
        //no.5
        Console.WriteLine("Question 3\n" + name + ",If you were in third place and you over take someone in second place what place would you be in now?\na.first\nb.second\nc.third\n");
        ansr5 = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();
        if ((ansr5 == "b") && (score == 4))
        {
            //bonus level
            Console.WriteLine("Congratulations" + name + "you have scored a perfect 5!\nWould you like to enter the bonus stage?\nIf you lose this you lose the game\nbut if you pass you will receive 5 points.\nYes, or No?");
            bonus1 = Console.ReadLine();
            if (bonus1 == "yes")
            {

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
        else if (ansr5 == "b")
        {
            score = score + 1;
            Console.WriteLine("Correct\n" + name + "'s score:" + score + "\n");
        }


        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wrong\n" + name + "'s score:" + score + "\n");
        }

        Console.Beep(1000, 1500);
        Console.Clear();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome. I am glad i could help you. :)